# How to track 'Implementer' in Jira (vs. Assignee)

Tags: workflow, jira, issue-tracking

Our JIRA workflow for development issues goes something like this:

```
New -> In-Progress -> Resolved -!-> Reviewed -> Closed/Released
```

This is simplified, but should get the point across.

The Jira Assignee for New/In-Progress is simple: It may start out being assigned to anyone, but as soon as it's in-progress the *developer* that codifies the issues is the Assignee.

When the developer *is done* he will check-in and set the issue to `Resolved`.

Now my "problem"(*) starts: Since the developer *should not* review the issue himself, the issue should be assigned to someone else for review. The reviewer can then approve it and set it to `Reviewed`, after which it is ready to be included in a release. (details on how that works not relevant here)

The issue then ends up with the Assignee set to the reviewer, where the relevant person for the issue is actually the original developer.

I mean: When looking at Jira issues, I'm mostly interested in the **Implementer**, not the person that approved the change afterwards.

So the question(s) seems to be:

- Jira Assignee seems to be *thought to* change through the transitions of issues.
- The Assignee may then well end up with a only secondary relevant person when the issue is finally closed. *This makes filtering on closed issues harder.*
- Is this a real problem, and what solutions are there for this?

I guess one could add additional fields, but the fact that the defaults only have these two People should hint at something?

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to address this. First, you can create a custom field called Implementor and put the value of the Assignee into it before transitioning to from Resolved to Reviewed. This is straightforward and would let you report on it easily. The more difficult approach would be to write a script that would review the Issue History and pick out the Assignee when the Issue was in development.